# Insert values of one list into another at every n position

Tags: python

Lots of examples on SO for inserting the same *single* value into another list at n positions, but can't find anything demonstrating the following:

Take the following lists:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] 
list2 = ['this', 'that', 'the', 'other']
```

Insert each value of list2 into list1 every 2 positions to return:

```
['a', 'b', 'this', 'c', 'd', 'that', 'e', 'f', 'the', 'g', 'h', 'other']
```

Alternatively just create a 3rd list with same result.

Comment: So did you try adapting the examples you found to your specific needs? What happened?

Comment: Yes I have a .py file which is a mess of attempts that isn't worth tidying up to post anything in here. This morning I thought this would be trivial. Seemingly not!

Comment: @ls22 if your question was answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references. You might ask for further clarification otherwise.

Comment: @Ares Yup, I know how to use SO ;) Still reviewing the answers as they're all pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[insert](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) can be used to insert a single value to the list

Let's see what the documentation says about `insert`:

> ## list.insert(i, x)
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first
>   argument is the index of the element **before** which to insert, so
>   `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a),
>   x)` is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

Inserts *before* the given index. Let's have a look at an example implementation keeping that in mind:

```
def ins_n(lst1, lst2, n):            # insert every n elements
  indx1 = n
  indx2 = 0
  while(indx1 <= len(lst1)):
    lst1.insert(indx1, lst2[indx2])
    indx1 += 1 + n                   # add `1` because we insert before the given index
    indx2 += 1
  return lst1
```

Test it with your example lists and `2`:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] 
list2 = ['this', 'that', 'the', 'other']

print(ins_n(list1, list2, 2))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'this', 'c', 'd', 'that', 'e', 'f', 'the', 'g', 'h', 'other']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with a list comprehension and chunk `list1` via [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9209546):

```
from itertools import chain

def chunks(L, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from L."""
    for i in range(0, len(L), n):
        yield L[i:i + n]

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] 
list2 = ['this', 'that', 'the', 'other']

zipper = zip(chunks(list1, 2), list2)
res = list(chain.from_iterable((x, y, z) for (x, y), z in zipper))

['a', 'b', 'this', 'c', 'd', 'that', 'e', 'f', 'the', 'g', 'h', 'other']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solution, simple and clean:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] 
list2 = ['this', 'that', 'the', 'other']

i=2
j=0
while(j<len(list1) and j<len(list2)):
    list1.insert(i, list2[j])
    i=i+3
    j=j+1

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code:

```
def insert_list(old_list, new_list, n):
    for i, val in enumerate(new_list):
        old_list.insert(n+i*3, val)
    return old_list
```

Test:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] 
list2 = ['this', 'that', 'the', 'other']
print(insert_list(list1, list2, 2))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'this', 'c', 'd', 'that', 'e', 'f', 'the', 'g', 'h', 'other']
```

Comment: I thought this answer was most elegant and ended up adapting it for my use case. I would have accepted the answer but just writing 'such?' isn't that useful for others who find this question in future. Keep up the good answers and consider adding a bit more context next time :)